# Typed redeemer in a minting policy

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I could not make the typed redeemer in the following minting policy work.  The redeemer was supposed to be `data MintAction = Mint | Burn`.  (I settled with the workaround `type MintAction = Bool`, with `False` representing `Mint` and `True` representing `Burn`.)

I get the error:

```shell
    * GHC stage restriction:
        instance for `UnsafeFromData
                        MintAction' is used in a top-level splice, quasi-quote, or annotation,
        and must be imported, not defined locally
    * In the first argument of `(.)', namely `mkUntypedMintingPolicy'
      In the Template Haskell quotation
        [|| mkUntypedMintingPolicy . emurgoMintingPolicyT ||]
      In the first argument of `PlutusTx.compile', namely
        `[|| mkUntypedMintingPolicy . emurgoMintingPolicyT ||]'
```

How to fix my minting policy?

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NumericUnderscores    #-}

module Minting where

-- import           Data.Aeson          (ToJSON, FromJSON)
-- import           GHC.Generics        (Generic)
import qualified PlutusTx
import qualified PlutusTx.AssocMap as M
import           PlutusTx.Prelude       as TxPrelude hiding (unless)
import           Plutus.Script.Utils.Typed (mkUntypedMintingPolicy)
import           Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value
import           Plutus.V2.Ledger.Api
import           Plutus.V2.Ledger.Contexts as V2LC

-- data MintAction = Mint | Burn
--   deriving (Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON)
-- PlutusTx.unstableMakeIsData ''MintAction

-- | A workaround since I could not make 'data MintAction = Mint | Burn' work
type MintAction = Bool

treasuryValHash :: ValidatorHash
treasuryValHash = ValidatorHash "deadbeef"

mintingCost :: Integer
mintingCost = 75_000_000

symbolValueOf' :: CurrencySymbol -> Value -> (Integer, Integer)
symbolValueOf' cs v = case M.lookup cs (getValue v) of
  Nothing        -> (0, 0)
  Just csTokens -> (minted, burned)
    where
      minted = foldr sum' 0 . M.toList $ M.filter (>0) csTokens
      burned = foldr sum' 0 . M.toList $ M.filter (<0) csTokens
      sum' = \(_, a) b -> a + b

{-# INLINABLE emurgoMintingPolicyT #-}
-- | Typed minting policy
emurgoMintingPolicyT :: TxOutRef -> MintAction -> V2LC.ScriptContext -> Bool
emurgoMintingPolicyT oref redeemer ctx =
  let
    info             = scriptContextTxInfo ctx
    (minted, burned) = symbolValueOf' (ownCurrencySymbol ctx) (txInfoMint info)
  in
    case redeemer of
      -- 'False' stands for 'Mint'
      False ->   minted == 1
              && burned == 0
              && (any (\txo -> case addressCredential . txOutAddress $ txo of
                          PubKeyCredential _  -> False
                          ScriptCredential vh -> vh == treasuryValHash &&
                            valueOf (txOutValue txo) adaSymbol adaToken >= mintingCost) $
                      txInfoOutputs info)
              && (any (\txIn -> txInInfoOutRef txIn == oref) $ txInfoInputs info)
      -- 'True' stands for 'Burn'
      True  -> minted == 0 && burned < 0

-- | Minting policy compiled to Plutus Core
policy :: TxOutRef -> MintingPolicy
policy oref = mkMintingPolicyScript $
  $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| mkUntypedMintingPolicy . emurgoMintingPolicyT ||])
  `PlutusTx.applyCode`
  PlutusTx.liftCode oref
```

Comment: It compiles. So, in what way does this policy not work and what are you doing to produce that result?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It does not seem to compile.  I edited my post adding the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with the use of Template Haskell. You can do this to prevent the error:

```haskell
policy :: TxOutRef -> MintingPolicy
policy oref = mkMintingPolicyScript $
  $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| wrap ||])
  `PlutusTx.applyCode`
  PlutusTx.liftCode oref
  where
    wrap = mkUntypedMintingPolicy . emurgoMintingPolicyT
```